# Create sample Microsoft Word document with invalid electronic signature

Tags: microsoft-word, digital-signature

I'm involved in informal education of notaries public. I would like to create a sample Microsoft Word document with a valid electronic signature, made with a digital certificate. I would then like to alter the document so the signature becomes invalid. I could then show the students what a document with an invalid signature because of tampering looks like.

If I try to do this with Word, it makes me click an "Edit anyway" box and removes the electronic signature as soon as I click. If I edit with Notepad, the document becomes corrupt and I can't load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps will work in Windows. I'll just use example folder paths:

1. Create a document with some sample text like TRUE to search for, and sign it
2. Copy your valid signed word document to `C:\temp\valid.docx`
3. Rename the file to `test.zip` (you may have to enable viewing file extensions)
4. Right-click the file > Extract All... > Extract. This should create a folder named valid
5. Open the file `C:\temp\valid\word\document.xml` in notepad
6. Edit some of the sample text (TRUE -> FALSE), save, and close the xml file
7. Select everything inside the `C:\temp\valid\` folder (you should see folders named `_rels` and `word` for example).
8. Right-click > Send to > Compressed (zipped) folder
9. Rename the zip file to `edited.docx`

When you open `edited.docx` in Word, the document will not be corrupted, you'll see the edited text, and you should get a notification showing invalid signatures

[image: screenshot]

Older .doc files and such work the same, but have slightly different internal file names

Comment: Thanks. I had tried pretty much the same thing, except I did things a little differently beginning at Cpt.Whale's step 7.

Comment: I tried your method and solved the problem as well.